# three.js TubeBufferGeometry position change for camera animation

Tags: javascript, three.js, buffer-geometry

I'am trying to change position/translate dinamicaly of TubeBufferGeometry.parameters.path which i will use for **camera animation** 
(all are based on this example: [webgl_geometry_extrude_splines](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=spli#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines))

here is my peace of code so far
full code: [Link to codesandbox with full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-euclid-koh1f)

Important part of code:

```
function init(){
    // initial scene render etc. for full code take a look at codesanbox

    // tube
    var extrudePath = new Curves.GrannyKnot();

    tubeGeometry = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry( extrudePath, 50, 2, 1, true );
    tubeGeometry.dynamic = true;

//unsuccessful approach to change the parameters of position
    tubeGeometry.translate(100, 0, 0)
    tubeGeometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    // animate camera along spline
    var time = Date.now();
    var looptime = 20 * 1000;
    var t = ( time % looptime ) / looptime;

    var pos = tubeGeometry.parameters.path.getPointAt( t );
    pos.multiplyScalar( 1 );

    splineCamera.position.copy( pos );
    renderer.render( scene, splineCamera );
}
```

The resault is giving me no translation of camera its moving around GrannyKnot curve in default position.

What i'm expecting is to dynamic change position/translate of **TubeBufferGeometry.parameters.path** in some direction (for example position X + 100) which affects on my camera movement

**EDIT**
I just realised that i could change camera by adding

```
function render() {
    // animate camera along spline
    var time = Date.now();
    var looptime = 20 * 1000;
    var t = ( time % looptime ) / looptime;

    var pos = tubeGeometry.parameters.path.getPointAt( t );
    pos.x += 100; //<----this line added
    pos.multiplyScalar( 1 );

    splineCamera.position.copy( pos );
    renderer.render( scene, splineCamera );
}
```

But if someone would show me how to change **TubeBufferGeometry.parameters.path** without changing definite pos.x like in code above it. I would be very glad for that.

Comment: [`.translate()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.translate) takes 3 floats as parameters, not `THREE.Vector3()`, if you want to shift a geometry at 10 units on x-axis, then do it like that: `geometry.translate(10, 0, 0);`. And what do you expect with this line: `tubeGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( extrudePath, 3, 1) );`? Why not change the position of your mesh, not shifting the geometry?

Comment: @prisoner849 thanks for replay. 
I checked docs again and u are right: translate takes floats parameters, but it still nothing happens when i'm applying like u wrote it. With second thing ```tubeGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( extrudePath, 3, 1) );``` i really don't know what i was expecting here (coulde be ignored). I am using TubeBufferGeometry for animation camera like i wrote (pls take a look on codesandobx for full code) so changing positin of mesh doesnt affect also. Propably wrongly form my question for help. i will edit this.

Comment: You might find the sample at the bottom of [this page](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-scenegraph.html) useful

Comment: Wow it's really good page didn't know it and i am really grateful for that, but unfortunately it's not solving my described problem.